# getsupportactionbar menu image

Tags: android, action

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_find"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
     android:actionViewClass="android.widget.ImageButton"/>
  </menu>
```

Simple code, i inflate this in menu

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.layout.menu_zain, menu);
    ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_find).getActionView();
    btn.setBackgroundResource(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        qal.setTitle("LeftTop Menu");
                        qal.setAnimationStyle(QuickActionList.ANIM_GROW_FROM_LEFT);
                        qal.setCalloutTintColor(Color.BLUE);
                        qal.show(v);
                    }
                });
    return true;
}
```

where does problem lie? the image is taking entire `height`/`width` on xhdpi. On ldpi its taking out of the Actionbar. how can i handle such situation?

Comment: I am not really sure what is going on there because of how you set things up. You are trying to set an image to the menu. But in your xml it is already doing that. So why don't you remove the code, or remove the xml that sets the drawable. Unless there is something I don't understand. But most importantly, why are you setting an on click listener? You should be handling that click on `onMenuItemSelected`

Comment: because on cant pass view on qal.show(v) in case of menuitemselected